# Memory Error with Pandas, better strategy?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, out-of-memory

I've encountered a Memory Error when attempting to perform multiple adjustments to a pandas dataframe. The idea is to incorporate a series of routine csv or excel files > conduct column combining or splitting > produce an updated dataframe than can be either exported back to csv or utilized for data analysis.

The data types consist of a combination of strings, integers, datetime objects, and the occasional boolean. I'm open to more efficient methodologies as well, thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C\filepath\'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.apped(df)
df1 = pd.concat(list_)

#Add new column from 'A' and 'B' columns
df2 = df1.assign(NewColumnName = df1['ColumnAName'] + '' + df1['ColumnBName'])

#Split another column into two separate columns
df3 = df2.join(df2['ColumnCName'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'NewColumnC1Name', 1:'NewColumnC2Name'}))
```

And so forth and so on. After about the 5th or 6th iteration, I experience MemoryError and as my understand is a bit limited, the indecies is reading millions of rows at this point creating a bog.

Edit- Error message contains the following:

```
File "pandas\_libs\join.pyx", line 123, in pandas._libs.join.left_outer_join

MemorryError
```

Comment: Please provide output containing the memory error.

Comment: what is `cancel`?

Comment: my error, edited 'cancel' with 'df1'